# Windows phone7: Open a webpage on button click?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I just searched, but didn't find a way to create a web link in my Windows phone7 Application. In Android TextView has `android:autoLink='Web'` In Windows phone7 textblock I didn't find any relevant property.

Tried adding the NavigateURI property in the Hyperlink and it gives an exception. `NavigateUri="http://www.google.com"`

Really appreciate If someone Can suggest How to do this. Thanks in Advance...!!!!!

Comment: I've edited my answer below. Please try it.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Yes, it works.. I tried with the properties..:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use just the HyperLinkButton Control.

And add this property to your control:

```
<HyperlinkButton TargetName="_blank" Content="Go To" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"/>
```

Finally add the click event handler to launch the browser using the BrowserTask :

```
 private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
     webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
     webBrowserTask.Show();
 }
```

Comment: Yes, When I add NavigateUri="http://www.google.com", in hyperlinkbutton it gives an Exception

Comment: Can you write the exception message please ?

Comment: Hi Haythern, But it gives the following warning [Microsoft.phone.tasks.WebBrowserTask.URL is obsolete. "Please use Uri property"

Comment: I've edited the answer try using Uri Property instead of URL.

Comment: Hi Haythern, We cant assign String URL for Uri. It give an error[Can not implicitly convert type string to System.uri]

Comment: Yes, That's it Haythern. Thanks