# Create lengthy webLink in Windows phone7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

In my Windows phone7 application I load some data from a XML feed. Some of them are links to Web pages. I used textblocks to display data. In my previous [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212678/open-a-webpage-on-button-click/8212716#8212716) I found how to open web page in HyperlinkButton.

But I cant use that way because HyperLinkButton doesn't have TextWrapping property and those links are lengthy. I need to show entire link and once user click the link, need to access the corresponding web page.

It would be great if someone can Suggest a way to achieve this. Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there could be a way around showing the entire link, lemme ask you this .. do you want to? How about just saying "Click 'here' ..." or something & let the user tap on it for navigation?

Please see some of the design guidelines for using the HyperLinkButton [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202899%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, here's a great post from Peter Kuhn on how to make HyperLinkButtons wrap: http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/WP7-snippet-analyzing-the-hyperlink-button-style.aspx Thanks!

Comment: Thanky you very much for your time and effort Samidip. I used this way. :)